# WAMP max_upload_filesize

Tags: php, file-upload, wamp

I am writing a PHP script to upload and re-size 4 images.
I have opted to use the method of giving 4 inputs the same name (an array):

```
<input type="file" name = "userfile[]" id="file1" />
<input type="file" name = "userfile[]" id="file2" />
<input type="file" name = "userfile[]" id="file3" />
<input type="file" name = "userfile[]" id="file4" />
```

I have set max_upload_filesize in wamp to 50M.
I have verified the max_uploads is set to default (20).
I have restarted all services and run php_info to verify this php.ini file was loaded.

My form-receiver page only does one thing:

```
var_dump($_FILES["userfile"]);
```

This works well, until file size approaches 8MB.
When the size of the uploaded files approache 8MB I get the error 
**Notice: Undefined index: userfile in C:\wamp\www\uploader\file_upload.php on line 2**

I have re-sized one image, pushing it up to 8MB size, and then tried ot upload 1 single file- this recreates the error.  I am certain that an 8MB limit exists here.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `post_max_size` and increase it's value.

Also, it's `upload_max_filesize`, not `max_upload_filesize`.